# Move a body from VecA to VecB, instantly, but properly affect other bodies

Tags: actionscript, box2d

I'm using the box2dflash library to create a game, and so far I've been using "SetPosition" to instantly move a body from one place to another... the problem is that it obviously skips affecting other bodies when I do this. I have the body set to bullet... now I just need to know how I calculate the force(?) to get the body to the exact coordinates that I need to move it to... preferably after only a single frame.

How would I go about doing this in box2d properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could SetLinearVelocity to the difference between the current location and the destination, multiplied by your frames per second. That should get the body there in one frame, then you will need to stop it! SetLinearVelocity again to zero would work.

Comment: That... was EXACTLY correct. How did you know that multiplying by the frames per second was the way to achieve this? I would have spent much too long reverse engineering the SetLinearVelocity code to find this sort of answer. I wish I could upvote this ten times!

Comment: Velocity is given in units per second, so it would take one second to get there if you simply set the velocity to the difference between the current and target locations. If your framerate is 60fps that would be 60 frames... if you want it there in one frame it'll need to be going 60 times faster :)